# Automatized action on scheduled date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, events

I need an action to be realized automatically when a specific date is reached in a MySQL database, so not necessarly when a user is logged in the site and does an action.
This would go for many different entries in the table.

For example, when UTC_TIMESTAMP() reaches 'release_date' for different items, a PHP script would be executed, respectively for each items.

This is something I have never approached before.
I'm reading about Cron Job and MySQL EVENTS. Would that be the way to go?

Thanks in advance! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Lois

Comment: It's a lot easier to trigger a PHP script execution with cron than it is using MYSQL Events; but if all you're doing is updating database records, why not do it using a MySQL stored procedure rather than a PHP script, the a MySQL event would be more appropriate

Comment: Mhh unfortunately, there would be more than only db records updates done but emails sent out etc.. So Cron seems to be the way to go. Thanks for your opinion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have a cron job that runs every time interval, you have full control of how often the script will run,

Within this script, you'll basically check the current time and see if it hits your 'release_date', then you run some queries against your db, if not, the script just exits.

so you can create a cron entry that runs every hour, like this

```
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.php
```

and inside `script.php`

```
#!/usr/bin/php
$release_date = 1383135371;
$now = time();
if($now >= $release_date){
 //Connect to database and do your code here
}
```

This way you'll have much more control of how things will work, this is not even scratching the surface of the powers of cron jobs !, let us know if things aren't clear :)

Comment: This is a great idea and gives me a good view on how to implement it easily. Thanks for your answer and time.

Comment: Anytime !, just let me know if anything seems blurry !

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a PHP script that would run your query, do your comparisons, and then run the appropriate scripts. You would then run this script from the command line via cron. Here's a page that describes it in more detail

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/

Comment: Thanks for your opinion and link! It seems indeed the way to go then. Geat to know!